# External CSS not working only on one page

Tags: html, css

As title suggests. I've just uploaded this to my site: http://kach.olympe.in/llsif/rare.php
The layout is very simple, the CSS as well, but it doesn't show up. And it's only on this page. The homepage and another have exactly the same code skeleton (I basically copy/pasted and changed the content), but the CSS doesn't work. If I put it internally directly, then it works. Even when I change `<link href="/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` to the full path, the CSS still doesn't work and I seriously can't figure out why. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If the page is the exact same, then you messed up on your copy-paste.  I would just try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add  @charset "utf-8" into the first line of your css file may help.